# If $AA$ and $BBB$ are equal to nothing, and $ABA = BB$, then does $AB = BA?$

Tags: group-theory

If there is a sequence of $A$s and $B$s, and a set of rules are defined so that subsequence $AA$ and $BBB$ can be inserted and deleted anywhere, and $ABA$ and $BB$ are interchangable. Then can $AB$ become $BA$ with this set of rules?

If $AB$ does equal to $BA$, then $B = BAA = ABA = BB = BBAA = BABA = BBB =$ nothing, so basically every sequence either equal to A or nothing, but I don't understand if this counts as a proof or not since I haven't figured out a way to prove that $B$ and nothing are fundamentally different according to these rules. I tried to consider it from a group theory perspective but I'm not good at group theory and neither does it seem to help.

Comment: What is meant with "equal to nothing" ?

Comment: @Peter "equal to an empty string"

Comment: In your proof you started from AB=BA and derived something. However what is needed is to *start* with one of AB or BA, perform a succession of moves using your rules, and wind up after these steps with the other. E.g. AB=???=???=...=BA.

Comment: The question describes a (symmetric) string rewriting system over the free monoid $\{A, b\}^*$. As both the generators $A$ and $B$ in the system are invertible ($A\cdot A=\epsilon$ and $B\cdot BB=\epsilon$), we have that the system defines a group - to be precise, it is simply the symmetric group $S_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this does not follow. Consider the group $S_3$ and let $a = (12)$ and $b = (123)$. Then $a^2$ and $b^3$ are both trivial, and indeed,
$$
aba = (12)(123)(12) = (132) \quad \text{and} \quad b^2 = (132).
$$
However,
$$
ab = (12)(123) = (23) \quad \text{and} \quad ba = (123)(12) = (13).
$$
So, there exists a group satisfying your conditions in which $ab \neq ba$, so this cannot possibly follow purely formally.

Comment: I have no idea how I didn't think of S3 before but now that you mention it its really the same structure as my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A$ to be complex conjugation and $B$ the multiplication by $e^{2\pi i/3}$. Then $A^2 = B^3 = \mathrm{id}$ and
$$ABAz = AB\bar{z} = A(e^{2\pi i/3}\bar{z}) = e^{4\pi i/3}z = B^2z$$
for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and therefore $ABA = B^2$. But
$$ABz = A(e^{2\pi i/3}z) = e^{4\pi i/3}\bar{z} \neq e^{2\pi i/3}\bar{z} = BAz,$$
therefore $AB \neq BA$. That is, $AB = BA$ cannot follow from your set of rules alone.

Answer (score 2):

The question must hold for groups, so a necessary condition is whether the group given by the presentation

$$P=\langle A,B\mid A^2, B^3, ABA=B^2\rangle$$

is abelian. But $P$ is a presentation for $S_3$, which is not.